# Action on press CCMenuItem. not on unpress

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I'm developing an app on cocos2d. I heard it is recommend to make my controls using CCMenu class. So, I made a button, set target and selector. But selector colled only when I unpress my button. how can I make it be called at rhe moment I pressed the button?

```
#import "Button.h"

@implementation Button

+ (id)buttonWithImage:(NSString*)file atPosition:(CGPoint)position target:(id)target selector:(SEL)selector {
    CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:[ButtonItem buttonWithImage:file target:target selector:selector], nil];
    menu.position = position;
    return menu;
}
@end

@implementation ButtonItem

+ (id)buttonWithImage:(NSString*)file target:(id)target selector:(SEL)selector {
    return [[[self alloc] initWithImage:file target:target selector:selector] autorelease];
}


- (id)initWithImage:(NSString*)file target:(id)target selector:(SEL)selector {
    if(self = [super initWithTarget:target selector:selector]) {

        back = [[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"DPad_BG.png"] retain];
        back.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);
        backPressed = [[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"DPad_BG.png"] retain];
        backPressed.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);
        [self addChild:back];

        self.contentSize = back.contentSize;

        CCSprite* image = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:file];
        [self addChild:image z:1];
        image.position = ccp(self.contentSize.width / 2, self.contentSize.height / 2);

    }
    return self;
}

-(void) selected {
    [self removeChild:back cleanup:NO];
    [self addChild:backPressed];
    [super selected];
}

-(void) unselected {
    [self removeChild:backPressed cleanup:NO];
    [self addChild:back];
    [super unselected];
}

// this prevents double taps
- (void)activate {
    [super activate];
    [self setIsEnabled:NO];
    [self schedule:@selector(resetButton:) interval:0.5];
}

- (void)resetButton:(ccTime)dt {
    [self unschedule:@selector(resetButton:)];
    [self setIsEnabled:YES];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [back release];
    [backPressed release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: Modify the CCMenu class, afaik there's no other way. CCMenu uses the "pressed" state to zoom in the item under the finger for visual feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I needed is place `[super activate];` to `-(void) selected` and remove it from `- (void)activate`

Comment: Two things, [super activate]; has been turned into [invocation_ invoke];   Secondly, I kept this line in BOTH selected and activate, then I set bools according to which was called --- So if it was yes already, I set it to no, and vice versa, (I was using this to create a jump effect for my game)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the method I added to the Cocos2d menuitems

```
CCMenuItemSprite* btn = [CCMenuItemSprite itemWithNormalSprite:sprite1 selectedSprite:sprite2 block:^(id sender) {
    //TODO: do stuff on release
}];
[btn setPressBlock:^(id sender) {
    //TODO: do stuff on press
}];
```

[Link to a Github commit with additional block copy for a on-press action](https://github.com/jllust/cocos2d-iphone/commit/89c2acdd127a95608a852fec38b9d384f26b4d5f)

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the method is run on button release just makes it nicer for the user to use as some people may have pressed the button, realized that it wasn't the button they wanted to press, and then move to another area of the screen before releasing. So, it really isn't recommended to have the method to be run on the button press.

Comment: I'm trying to make a control buttons for the game. I really need to do some action on button press.

Comment: There are still reasons for needing on-press vs just on-release. For example, while holding down a button, a fan spins, once released it's slows to a stop again. I recommend there is a need to have a method for on button press. I'll keep looking.

Comment: @LeeIII In that case, you'd want to create a sprite and then whenever the touch is detected on that sprite, it calls a method of your choosing (which could include the fan's spinning animation for example).

Answer (score 0):

To Create Menu You try this Code..

```
CCMenuItemImage *Item = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"yourImage.png" selectedImage:@"yourSelectedImage.png" target:self selector:@selector(clicked)];
CCMenu *Menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:Item, nil];
[self addChild:Menu];
```